# Trouble with Select by Location

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I'm having trouble selecting individual the corresponding polygon in my parcel data based on the location of a property. It seems obvious, but what am I missing?

I have a list of geocoded properties labeled as "active". Then I also have polygon parcel data. I'd like to iterate through the list of active properties and determine which parcel and the accompanying data that corresponds to.

I am trying to use Select by Location, however it is not returning any values. Any thoughts?

**Model builder that iterates through the active properties, then Selects the correct polygon based on the Selected feature from active in the iteration**
**[image]**

**Image of the parcels and the active properties**
[image]

Comment: Repair Geometry on your parcels and selecting features, a failure in selection is likely to be caused by an incorrect ring orientation or hourglass polygon which will be rectified by repair geometry.

Comment: @MichaelStimson seemed logical, unfortunately this didn't work. I tried Repairing Geometry of file and re-adding the data, then I also tried adding a Repair Geometry to the actual modelBuilder during every iteration. Neither worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are the points multipart or a different coordinate system to your parcels?

Comment: @hornbydd the points are just coordinates plotted straight from one of my stand alone csv tables. I’m also using those same points to do a separate select by location in the same model builder.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think I actually misunderstood your question. I didn't know there were even different coordinate systems. It looks like the select features are GCS WGS 1984 & the parcel data is GCS North American 1983 Feet. What's the recommended way to get these on the same page or fix this issue?

Comment: How is select by location "not returning any values"? In your model screen shot you don't have any tools hooked up to select, nor have you made anything a parameter. What are you expecting to happen when you run the model that isn't happening?

Comment: @kHibma did my image get cut off or did I mess this up that bad? I have a select layer by location tool in there that has the selected features variable as the selector and then the parcel polygon variable as the input. The tool is set for intersect. I would expect it to select the parcel that the selector intersects with. How should it be set up?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

As indicated by Hornbydd, the layers had different coordinate systems. You can check this in ArcGIS Pro by going to Properties > Spatial Reference > Geographic Coordinate System. The solution was to take my parcel data and "Reproject it" using the project tool. Just make sure when you project it you are using the same coordinate system as your other items.

A detailed explanation is here: http://www.resourcesupplyllc.com/PDFs/Reproject%20Coordinate%20Systems%20in%20ArcGIS.pdf

Comment: David if you are doing any sort of analysis using distance, or reporting distance/area values I would recommend when you project the datasets to a common coordinate system you choose the coordinate system that is in Feet or Metres. Trying to process/report data that is in decimal degrees is meaningless to most people but everyone understands Feet/Metres.

Comment: Also you should tick your reply to you question as answered so people know that this question has a solution.

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer for another 14 hours but I will accept it when I can. Thanks Hornbydd!